# How to highlight comments on the current line differently in Vim?

Tags: vim

I'm trying to customise my Vim syntax highlighting, but I can't figure out how to do this one thing.
The relevant parts are:

```
hi Comment guifg=#5c6370 ctermfg=241
hi CursorLine guifg=#313640 ctermfg=237
```

This part works just as I desire, but I'd like to make an additional case, where **comments *on* the cursor line** have colour `#282c34`/`236`.

This is something I've tried after reading the Vim docs, but it seems to have no effect.

```
syn keyword CurrentComment Comment CursorLine
hi CurrentComment guifg=#282c34 ctermfg=236
```

I expected this to create a syntax group for comments on the cursor line, and colour the appropriate text accordingly. However, all comments were still coloured as before, even the ones on the current line.

Any help on how else I could do this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I am not particularly familiar with the content of Vim syntax highlighting, but here I have an idea, maybe not so perfect.

First, assuming that the comment always fills the entire line. You only need to detect whether the syntax group under the current cursor is `Comment` every time the `CursorMoved` event is triggered. If yes, highlight the current line with new highlight group `CurrentComment` using `matchaddpos` function, otherwise, only clear the `CurrentComment` highlight group added last time. The example code is as follows:

```
hi Comment guifg=#5c6370 ctermfg=241
hi CurrentComment guifg=#282c34 ctermfg=236

autocmd CursorMoved * if exists('w:match_id')
            \|          call matchdelete(w:match_id) | unlet w:match_id
            \|        endif
            \|        if synIDattr(synID(line('.'), col('.'), 1), 'name') =~? 'comment'
            \|          let w:match_id = matchaddpos('CurrentComment', [line('.')])
            \|        endif
```

Of course, there are some details you need to implement. For example, the comment may appears at the end of the line instead of entire line. So to be more accurate, you should detect whether the current line contains comments, not whether there is a comment under the cursor. Correspondingly, you need to pass in the exact position to the `pos` parameter of the `matchaddpos` function.

This may be what you need: `:h synID()`, `:h synIDtrans()`, `:h synIDattr()`, `:h matchadd()`, `:h matchaddpos()`, `:h matchdelete()`, `:h clearmatches()`, `:h CursorMoved`, `:h CursorMovedI`.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to implement this later! I'd like it to highlight comments that don't start at the beginning of the line as well, so maybe those functions you listed will be useful.